# crow feet notation in enterprise atchitect

Tags: data-modeling, enterprise-architect

I am using Enterprise Architect (version 10.0) and would like to see crow's feet notation in my ER model. so I have changed the setting to 'Information Engineering' then the notation is diappeared. Now i can't see any notation in the model.

Any help really appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED** - To see Crows feet, you may have to use the 'association' connector from the data modeling toolbox, Using the ERD connector isn't reflecting it)